# C# WP8 Service Reference changed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-express, service-reference

I'm working on Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone and I added a service reference for my project. It has been working good since I added it.

Yesterday I started building the layout for my app and then I noticed that my service reference is not the same like it was before. It still works but it's icon is different now and it doesn't give me the same right click options like before.

Image 1: http://snag.gy/kvGJV.jpg

Image 2: http://snag.gy/RjTys.jpg

Notice how the icon changed, it's now a folder icon, it used to be a little globe or something like that. And in the right click options it doesn't say "Update service reference" or "Configure service reference"...

What happened? And how can I update my service reference now? (The IP changes a lot)

Edit: I discovered that if I start a new project and then use Blend my service reference changes to a folder. My questions stills the same, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of this problem. It seems there is a bug when using Blend and Visual Studio at the same time. When you make changes in your project with Blend, Visual Studio asks if you want to reload only the files with modifications or if you want to reload all files. Somehow, if you choose to reload all files it makes modifications to your service reference resulting in errors and other changes.

Comment: How did you end up fixing it?  I deleted and re-added the services, but didn't like going that route because I couldn't remember what services I'd set to have a different collection type. Some were System.Collections.Generic.List. Others were System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection.  Ultimately, the compiler griped when I guessed wrongly.

Comment: I tried to re-add the service like you but it was too late, it gave me many errors. I had to open an old version of my project and start from that :/ Make sure you make backups of your project if you are using Blend + Visual Studio with a service reference.

Comment: somehow the only solution now is to delete the service reference and re-adding it back but it just plain troublesome